# Completion of $C^n([a,b])$ with respect to $L^2$ norm

Tags: functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral

I was wondering what is the completion of $C^n([a,b])$ under $L^2$ norm? Is it the whole $L^2$ space or just a dense subset of $L^2$?

Comment: The completion of a space is always (by definition) closed, so in the case it is dense it must be the whole space.
Also, the polynomials in $[a,b]$ are dense in $L_2[a,b]$ under the $2$-norm, so since they are included in $C^n[a,b]$, this must be also dense in $L_2[a,b]$ under the $2$-norm

Comment: @Klaramun Is it possible to do the completion without referring to a specific norm? similar to what we did for real number set R

Comment: When you do the completion of the rationals in order to get the reals you are doing it under a specific norm, which is the typical absolute value. In general the completion of a space under a certain norm is simply filling the possible "gaps" you may have in your space, by allowing all the possible limits you can take under this norm in your space. So the completion is referred to a specifid norm always. E.g. the completion of the cont. functions under the sup-norm is the space of cont. functions itself (uniform limit of cont.functions is cont.), so the completion strongly depends on the norm.